# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'insuranceController':

Tags: spring, maven, mybatis, autowired

I am new to Spring and I am trying to make an application for learning but I am getting problems with Autowiring, I am adding my code and Error message HTTP 500. I am working on maven Spring with IntelliJ.

Please Help me....

root-context.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${spring.database.class}" />
        <property name="url" value="${spring.database.host}" />
        <property name="username" value="${spring.database.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${spring.database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

InsuranceController.java

```java
package com.insurance.controller;

import com.insurance.mybatis.dao.InsuranceDAO;
import com.insurance.mybatis.dto.InsuranceDTO;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.List;   

@Controller
public class InsuranceController {
    @Autowired
    InsuranceDAO insuranceDAO;

    @RequestMapping(value="/insurance")
    public String test( ModelMap modelMap ){
        modelMap.addAttribute( "text", "안녕하세요" );
        return "mybatis/insurance";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/insuranceList")
    public String insuranceList( Model model ){
        List<InsuranceDTO> list = insuranceDAO.list();
        model.addAttribute("list", list);
        model.addAttribute( "text", "안녕하세요" );
        return "mybatis/insuranceList";
    }
}
```

InsuranceDAO

```java
package com.insurance.mybatis.dao;

import com.insurance.mybatis.dto.InsuranceDTO;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public interface InsuranceDAO {
    public List<InsuranceDTO> list();
}
```

InsuranceDAOImpl

```java
package com.insurance.mybatis.dao;

import com.insurance.mybatis.dto.InsuranceDTO;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.List;

//@Repository
@Service
public class InsuranceDAOImpl implements InsuranceDAO{
    @Autowired
    SqlSession sqlSession; 

    @Override
    public List<InsuranceDTO> list() {
        return sqlSession.selectList( "insurance.list" );
    }
}
```

InsuranceDTO

```java
package com.insurance.mybatis.dto;

public class InsuranceDTO {
    private int insuranceID, insuranceCost;
    private String insuranceName, content, type;

    public int getInsuranceID() {
        return insuranceID;
    }

    public void setInsuranceID(int insuranceID) {
        this.insuranceID = insuranceID;
    }

    public int getInsuranceCost() {
        return insuranceCost;
    }

    public void setInsuranceCost(int insuranceCost) {
        this.insuranceCost = insuranceCost;
    }

    public String getInsuranceName() {
        return insuranceName;
    }

    public void setInsuranceName(String insuranceName) {
        this.insuranceName = insuranceName;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Error Message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvRJI.png)

Below is the Major reason for error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'insuranceController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'insuranceDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.insurance.mybatis.dao.InsuranceDAO' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:364)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:624)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1650)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzbwT.png)

Comment: Can you please add your main class to your question? Thanks!

Comment: Most likely the package `com.insurance.mybatis.dao` is not scanned.

Comment: I add Project folder Structure.

Comment: I don't know what is main class....

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? If so, you should have a class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`. Do you?

Comment: No I just use spring maven.

Comment: So you simply use Spring Framework but not Spring Boot. Do you have any `@ComponentScan` annotation?

Comment: No, I don't... I don't know where I write @ComponentScan annotation...

Comment: @24you You should read the [doc](http://mybatis.org/spring/).